# Change Pivot table data source using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to automatically try to change the "Data Source" of a pivot table in excel. I have tried most if not all of the solutions available on Google/Stack Overflow. However I keep encountering the following error.

```
Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument
```

Here is the code that I'm running that fails.

```
Sub UpdateResourcePivots()
Dim pivotDataSheet As Worksheet
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Dim pivotLocation As String
Dim pivotDesignation As String
Dim startPoint As Range
Dim endPoint As Range
Dim dataRange As Range
Dim newRange As String
Dim lastRow As Integer

Dim newPivotCache As PivotCache

Set pivotDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PivotData")
Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Team Information")

pivotLocation = "pvtResourceLocation"
pivotDesignation = "pvtResourceDesignation" 'Dont worry about this one for now

Set startPoint = dataSheet.Range("A5")
lastRow = dataSheet.Range("A" & dataSheet.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
Set endPoint = dataSheet.Range("O" & lastRow)
Set dataRange = dataSheet.Range(startPoint, endPoint)

newRange = "'" & dataSheet.name & "'!" & dataRange.Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True, ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, External:=True)
' newRange = "'" & dataSheet.name & "'!" & dataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) ' Tried this as well

Set newPivotCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=newRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10)

With pivotDataSheet
    .PivotTables(pivotLocation).ChangePivotCache newPivotCache 'Error thrown here.

End With
End Sub
```

The error is thrown at the following line:

```
.PivotTables(pivotLocation).ChangePivotCache newPivotCache
```

Some other info

> I am using MS Office 2010 (licensed).
>   I have one source of data (a small table with 20 rows and 8 columns; the rows will grow hence the macro). Created two Pivot Tables on another sheet. On a third sheet I'm using Slicers to filter the data (Dashboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code so that you create the cache as you assign it to the pivot table:

```
With pivotDataSheet
    .PivotTables(pivotLocation).ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=dataRange.Address(Referencestyle:=xlR1C1), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10)
```

Comment: I've accepted this as an answer as I was trying to simplify the code and I also incorporated your recommendation and it worked. 

However I don't think this is the only answer as I was using the above code (as this is the most recommended code on the internet) and it kept failing me. I think I had over complicated the Ranges. Anyhow thanks for the help @Rory